# 'statusChangeCallback' is not defined Facebook Javascript SDK Login Error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

For **New Developers** who are trying to integrate facebook login and authentication in their websites, they might receive the error if they'll simply try to copy the tutorial from Facebook Help for Developers.

Error is : *Uncaught ReferenceError: statusChangeCallback is not defined*

[image: Uncaught ReferenceError: statusChangeCallback is not defined]

Code:

```
    <script>
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
          FB.init({
              appId: '<Your App ID>',
              cookie: true,
              xfbml: true,
              version: 'v2.12'
          });

          FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

      }; 
    </script>

    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email"
                     onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    </fb:login-button> 

<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: @CBroe the url that you gave obviously carries the complete answer however when you'll create a new app using create app and click on choose platform then there will be initial help screen in which facebook will you code to copy and paste. When you'll follow all those steps then you'll notice that the function mentioned here was missing in that copy paste tutorial. So here one developer tried this and got error on console. I thought of answering as stackoverflow gives this option. If you don't like self answering option in stackoverflow then you must appeal to community to disable this feature

Comment: Sorry, wasn't really clear that you were referring to a different place where code was presented. I removed the close vote and above comment.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solution is that new developers are **forgetting to write success callback function** in their code. The problem occurs when they try to copy the code from Facebook's Guide that comes immediately after Facebook App Registration.

In your HTML define a div with id status `<div id="status"></div>` just before the `<script>` tag.

Please include the javascript method below for the API to work. I have written some console.log verbose text. You can delete this text and replace with yours.

```js
   function statusChangeCallback(response) {
                console.log('statusChangeCallback');
                console.log(response);
                // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
                // app know the current login status of the person.
                // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
                // for FB.getLoginStatus().
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                          'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
                    });
                } else {
                    // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                      'into this app.';
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Still has an error like "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" in console, but comparing with callback function, it is really minor.

Comment: @pluto just declare a div with id status `<div id=status></div>`

Comment: It’s not forgetting, they don’t know they have to do it.

Comment: @JulianWagner yeah its not obvious from the documentation.  If they'd have changed the line `statusChangeCallback(response);` to `console.log(response)` it would have been a bit more obvious.

Comment: @vibs2006 do you have any advice as to how to integrate this with a standard php login system?